# java, transfer first 3 bits from one byte to another in a single operation

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit

I want to transfer the first 3 bits from one byte to another. Currently I use the following but its too slow (incorrect branch prediction slows things down)>

```
    byte newByte = 0;
    if(((oldByte >> 0)&1) == 1)  newByte |= 1 << 0;
    if(((oldByte >> 1)&1) == 1)  newByte |= 1 << 1;
    if(((oldByte >> 2)&1) == 1)  newByte |= 1 << 2;
```

How do I do this in a single operation without if statements or loops?

Note: other bits beyond bit num 3 may or may not be set in oldByte but I want to ignore them.

I tried using newByte |= oldByte but it transfers the set bits beyond bit num 3 which is not what I want.

any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
byte newByte = (byte) (oldByte & 0b111);
```

will do the trick. This works because 0b111 works as a mask, so only the rightmost three bits in `oldByte` will keep their original value after the calculation has been performed; the rest of the bits in `oldByte` will be set to 0. The result will then be assigned to `newByte`. You need to cast the result to a `byte` because the bitwise & operator produces an `int`, which is larger than a `byte` and so must be cast to convert properly.

If you want to get the first *n* bits from oldByte instead of the first 3 bits, you can do something like this:

```
byte newByte = (byte) (oldByte & ((1 << n) - 1));
```

Example when `n == 3`:

```
(1 << n) - 1
(1 << 3) - 1
0b1000 - 1
0b111
```

Comment: Good answer.  You'll have to cast the result to a `byte` before you can assign it though, right?

Comment: @sstan You are correct. I'm editing the answer with that information.

Comment: Would the following work as well?  byte newByte = oldByte & (byte)9b111;

Comment: @DeanJ `byte newByte = oldByte & (byte) 0b111;` does not work, because even if both operands are of type `byte`, the result is still `int`. I'm not sure why, though.

Comment: It's a rule defined in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2).